# datepicker jump to a date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want datepicker to jump to a date but I don't want to select that date.
I saw a method setDate in the documentation. I want exactly what it does but it should not select the date.

e.g.

- if the datepicker is showing 'Mar 2012'
- I call a method jumpToDate('02/02/2011')
- the datepicker should now jump to Feb 2011
- But it should not select '02/02/2011' rather previously selected date should persist.

Comment: By "jump" do you mean visually highlight the date in the calendar?

Comment: No, I mean the datepicker should start showing that date.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you mean by the previous date "persisting" then. Do you just want to keep track of it in case you want to restore it?

Comment: I want the calendar to show the new date but the selection should not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on jQuery UI source code and my previous tries on a similar topic, I wrote this function:

```
function gotoDate($j, month, year) {
    $j.each(function (i, el) {
        var inst = $.datepicker._getInst(el);
        inst.drawMonth = inst.selectedMonth = month;
        inst.drawYear = inst.selectedYear = year;
        $.datepicker._notifyChange(inst);
        $.datepicker._adjustDate(el);
    });
}
```

This is based on undocumented method calls and could change in a future version of jQuery UI.

See a [live fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gpoussel/rJ8ZV/)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Thanks all others who tried to help me out.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for - probably wouldn't have figured this out on my own ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use setDate but remove the value after that so the input field with the date is empty after that "jump"